# Why is the Python interpreter from my Anaconda environment faster than from VS2017?

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda

I have two Python environments: one from Visual Studio 2017 and one from Anaconda.

I found that the first one is twice as slow as the second, even if I run `*.py` scripts not via Visual Studio shell, but directly from command line using `python.exe`:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe  example.py
```

takes 10.1 seconds, and

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe  example.py
```

takes 5.1 seconds.

What could be the reason of such behavior?

Comment: Where does the Visual Studio version of python come from? I have to wonder if there is a debugger baked into that executable.

Comment: It comes from standard python package for VS.I also thought about the debugger but it is slow even if I run scripts directly with python.exe,  no VS shell or any other stuff

Comment: You could try and add `-v` (i.e. `python -v example.py`) to see which modules get imported by each interpreter.